# Load trace file into SQL Server - Access is Denied

Tags: sql-server

So at work I've been given a 500MB trace file to try and diagnose some issues. We've found a few culprits I think are the problems but they want me to run some queries against the data to prove my hypothesis. I installed SQL Server 2017 Developer locally so I could have a local database to mess with and can't get it to work.

```
DROP TABLE TraceTemp;
SELECT * INTO TraceTemp FROM::fn_trace_gettable('C:\Users\chalewis\Desktop\sql.trc',default);
```

I keep getting the following error. File 'C:\Users\chalewis\Desktop\sql.trc' either does not exist or there was an error opening the file. Error = '5(Access is denied.)'.

- Database and file are on same machine so the path should be correct (used copy as path windows function to get it).
- I'm logged in using Windows Authentication and can load the file into
  SQL Server Profiler just fine.
- The trace was captured by SQL Server Profiler.
- I have given permission to my desktop to {ComputerName}/MSSQLSERVER

Anything else I can possibly do?

Comment: I would guess that the service account does not have access to the location `C:\Users\chalewis\Desktop\sql.trc`. SQL Server shouldn't really have access to other user's documents as well. I suggest placing the file in a location that isn't your desktop and then giving the service account access to that folder (if it does not already).

Comment: I moved it to C:\ and it worked. Tried giving mssqlserver permissions, but guess it must not use that or my credentials to try and access the file :(

Comment: No, SQL server doesn't use your credentials (or the credentials of whomever is running the query) to access a file when it accesses a folder, it uses that of the account the service is running as.

Answer (score 0):

The access to the folder/file is normally done with the user your Sql Server service is running (check via services.msc) and give this user access rights to the folder (I guess it's `NT Service\MSSQLSERVER` in your case).